# Parameter expansion resulting in empty string is treated differently

Tags: bash

### Update

Someone in [bug-bash mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-bash) has [confirmed](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-10/msg00100.html) this is a bug.

---

If anyone's interested, a fix is available in [the latest commit to devel branch](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?h=devel&id=f48a4895858ef09d35eb83143a35c4fb223592a2).

---

While

```
bash -c 'echo "${1##*""}"' _ bar
```

prints an empty line,

```
bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar
```

prints `bar`.

I don't understand this. `${1##*}` expands to an empty string, so `"${1##*}"` should be treated just as `""` is, but seems like bash doesn't think so.

There seems to be a consensus on this among other popular `sh` implementations:

```
$ sh -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ ash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ dash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ ksh -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ ksh93 -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ mksh -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ posh -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ yash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$ zsh -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar

$
```

bash (with or without `--posix`) is the only one not conforming to that:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1##*}"}"' _ bar
bar
```

And without substring processing thingies the behavior is as expected:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1+}"}"' _ bar

$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${2}"}"' _ bar

$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${2}"}"' _ bar ''

$
```

I really wonder if there is an explanation for this, which I couldn't find in the manual. Is this a bug, or a misinterpretation of the standard? Is this behavior documented somewhere?

---

PS: I know a quick workaround is to unquote the inner PE, but that doesn't answer my question, and may lead to undesired results with strings containing special characters.

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)` prints an empty string

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` prints "bar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This is not an answer*

First I was thinking that this is due to special glob-rules, but in the end I think this is a bug in bash. The following four examples should give you a feeling why I believe this is a bug:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*${1%%bar}}"' _ foobar        # case 1
bar
$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*${1%%foobar}}"' _ foobar     # case 2

$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1%%bar}"}"' _ foobar      # case 3
bar
$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${1%%foobar}"}"' _ foobar   # case 4
foobar
```

Case 1 and case 3 differ in the quotes. But parameter expansion of the form `${parameter##word}` use pathname expansion rules to process `word`. So `*foo` and `*"foo"` have identical behaviour as double-quotes in pathname expansion can be ignored unless they embrace special pattern characters (`*`,`?`,...). This is seen in the following example:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*${2%%b*r}}"' _ 'foobar' 'f*ob*r'
bar
$ bash -c 'echo "${1##*"${2%%b*r}"}"' _ 'foobar' 'f*ob*r'
foobar
```

> So if this is the case, why should Case 2 and Case 4 behave differently?

Comment: *why should Case 2 and Case 4 behave differently?* No reason, both `${1+}` and `${1+""}` expands to empty string, but they are not treated the way `${1##*}` is (see my latest edit). Thus we can deduce this is a bug, right?

Comment: @oguzismail Exactly! If case 1 and case 3 behave identical, then case 2 and case 4 should also behave identically.